# how to pull all new changes in local repository using pipeline script in Jenkins? how to setup trigger to developer?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, git-pull

I'm trying to pull new changes from remote branch to test server, how to setup pipeline job only for git pull & need to setup trigger for a developer using ssh.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please elaborate a bit more? I don't understand, what you want to achieve.

Comment: whenever new changes in developer branch , we have to pull changes into UAT local repo .

Comment: What is this local repo? You want to execute `git pull`? How do you see that related to Jenkins

Comment: I have a dev/uat/prod servers, in each server, there is a git repo, the developer made some changes in branch & push to a server, then I want update repo's in UAT also.